# Direction arrows (or lines) at node

Tags: geometry-generator, direction, nodes

I've got a set of lines "passing through" a node.
The passing links are directional (not all possible combinations) I want to make arrows (line with marker) for each node to display what is and what isn't possible.
I've already made something like that (arrows with offsets along whole links):[image]

I want this arrows to be short, starting and ending before node 78, but keeping angles of the "outer" links - something like junction lane information sign (before junction).

I want to use Geometry Generator for that.
I can reduce arrows length using simple:

```
make_line(
    line_interpolate_point($geometry, distance_to_vertex($geometry,1) - 999), 
    point_n($geometry,2), 
    line_interpolate_point($geometry, distance_to_vertex($geometry,1) + 999))
```

but I want to keep "whole" arrows before the node, because it's still not "readable":[image]

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some visually better solution, where arrows have some "defined" offset to the left, defined by perpendicular distance to link (azimuth - 90 degrees). Since every arrow should have different distance from main link I used table field "frOut" defining which of the turns is it.

```
translate(
    translate(
        make_line(
            line_interpolate_point($geometry,
                distance_to_vertex($geometry,1) - 600), 
            point_n($geometry,2), 
            line_interpolate_point($geometry,
                distance_to_vertex($geometry,1) + 300)
        ),
        (x(start_point($geometry))-x(point_n($geometry,2)))*0.3,
        (y(start_point($geometry))-y(point_n($geometry,2)))*0.3
    ),
    ("frOut"*150+200)*sin(-radians(90)+azimuth(
            start_point($geometry),
            point_n($geometry,2)
        )),
    ("frOut"*150+200)*cos(-radians(90)+azimuth(
            start_point($geometry),
            point_n($geometry,2)
        ))
)
```

Result still isn't perfect, but it's still a bit better (there is additional turn 93->97 not existing before):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Probably easiest solution is to use function translate with X,Y deltas.

```
translate(
    make_line(
        line_interpolate_point($geometry,
            distance_to_vertex($geometry,1) - 999), 
        point_n($geometry,2), 
        line_interpolate_point($geometry,
            distance_to_vertex($geometry,1) + 999)
    ),
    (x(start_point($geometry))-x(point_n($geometry,2)))*0.3,
    (y(start_point($geometry))-y(point_n($geometry,2)))*0.3
)
```

It's still far from perfect, but I'll have to rethink how to draw those arrows, offset isn't good as small angles (measured clockwise) have short arrows while big angles - much longer.

Anyways: translate function is a simple answer to given question.
[image]

Comment: Looks like you are quite close to a solution. It seeems like an interesting problem. Can you share some example data and a style file (qml) that includes your current geometry generator expression?

Comment: It's a bit more complicated, since this virtual layer based on Excel-imported table (atNode, fromNode, toNode; with some flow values that should be visualized), combined with node locations (point geo-layer). But I'll share more when I get closer to some "final" solution.